# How to compare dates from MongoDB object in python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to work out the difference in years between a MongoDB object and Today's date. The MongoDB object looks like this:

```
Key: Value

club_joined: 2021-08-10T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

I have the python code (that works):

```py
loyal_players = []

for player in players.find():
    # get time players have been at club
    current_date = datetime.today()
    joined_club = player['club_joined']

    time_at_club = relativedelta(current_date, joined_club)
    time_at_club_years = time_at_club.years

    # check if they are over 10 years
    if time_at_club_years >= 10:
        loyal_players.append(player['short_name'])
```

But what I want is a Mongo query that can add into the `.find()` line:

```py
for player in players.find():
```

I know the logic behind it is:

```
for player in players.find(
    where (
        (todayDate - player['club_joined']) > 10
    ):
```

But how do I write this as a MongoDB query in python?

---

MongoDb Type:

[image]

Comment: Double checking:  is `club_joined` an ISO8601 string?   Not a real mongodb datetime?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti no, it is a `Date`, I will add a screenshot to my question to show

Comment: @RC07JNR Would you be able to just covert to timestamp milliseconds and take the difference, and calculate the days/months/years? Or would that be too consuming for your app (after querying the data)

Comment: @Jacob If that can be added into the `.find()` of the MongoDD line that would probably work but I'm not sure how to do that!

Comment: @RC07JNR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852223/query-mongo-on-timestamp - Would this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$subtract` function will take 2 dates and return the diff in millis so this works:

```
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    import datetime

    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    TARG = 86400 * 1000 * 365 * 10 # secs in day X millis X 365 days X 10 yrs                            

    cursor = db.foo.aggregate([
        {"$match": {"$expr": {"$gt": [ {"$subtract": [now,"$club_joined"]}, TARG ] } }}
    ])
    for doc in cursor:
        print(doc)
```

Comment: I think this is along the right line! That gives me the following error tho: Unresolved attribute reference 'datetime' for class 'datetime'. My import = `from datetime import datetime` and the line is exactly what you have, any ideas?

Comment: I added the 2 imports to my answer as they appear in my working example.  Don't be shy to accept the answer and upvote.  ;-)

Comment: Aww amazing! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Using [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) seems simpler:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

dt = datetime.datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=10)

cursor = db.foo.find({'club_joined': {'$lt': dt}})

for doc in cursor:
    print(doc)
```

Comment: It does.   I am a\lways trying to demo the agg functions.

Answer (score 0):

Following code with logic of expire time of 3 mintues of previously inserted data works fine.

```
today = datetime.today()
time_threshold = today - timedelta(minutes=3)


data = mongo_client[db_name][f'{instrument_name}'].find_one({
    "$or": [
        {
            "$and": [
                {"updated_at": {"$lt": time_threshold}},
                {"updated_at": {"$exists": True}},
            ]
        },
        {
            "$and": [
                {"generated": "Error"},
                {"updated_at": {"$exists": False}},
            ]
        },
    ],
})
```